Get user assignments to Azure AVD application group with python sdk
I'm trying to get the assignments of an AVD application group, but I do not see any way to do it in the python azure sdk:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-desktopvirtualization/azure.mgmt.desktopvirtualization.models.applicationgroup?view=azure-python
Is there any other way using python to get which users are assigned to that application group?

Could you please share the code, what you have tried?

I couldn't try any code since there's nothing related to assignments in host pools classes. I was wondering if there's a different way of doing this that I don't know of


Get user assignments to Azure AVD application group with python sdk.
Is there any other way to get which users are assigned to that application group?

Alternatively, you can also fetch the users who are assigned to the application group in AVD.
    $APGroupname = Get-AzWvdApplicationGroup -ResourceGroupName "RG_Name" -Name "application_group_name"
    $appGroupName | ForEach-Object {
        $name = $_.Name
        $AVDassign = Get-AzRoleAssignment | Where-Object { $_.Scope -like "*/$name" }
        $assignment | Select-Object DisplayName, ObjectType, @{N = 'ActionGroup'; E = { $_.Scope.Split('/')[-1] } }
    }

After running the PowerShell script, the users assigned to the application group are displayed.
Output:

Reference: Azure Virtual Desktop get list of users/groups assigned to Application Group with PowerShell

Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I need it in python, not Powershell.

As you mentioned in the question, is there any alternate way to achieve the same requirement, so I provided the solution using PowerShell, will check and let you know about Python.

I specified in the title "with python sdk", but I understand the confusion. I edited the text to make it more clear. Sorry for the inconvenience.
